# SharePoint 2016 migration error: User Exists: Cannot create duplicate user profile

Tags: sharepoint

I have migrated SharePoint 2010 site to SP 2013 and then to SP 2016 by Database backup and restore. This site has custom code (wsp). Steps performed:

1. Database backup and restore
2. Custome code worked post changing target framework to 4.5
3. Database mounting
4. Created new webapp and pointed database to it.

Issues occured:

1. File Not Found - resolved by changing master page

Current issue is, whenever I save I get below error:

```
Message: User Exists: Cannot create duplicate user profile.
Detail: 
at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager.CreateUserProfile(String strAccountName, String strPreferredName) at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager.CreateUserProfile(String strAccountName) at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager.CreateUserProfile() at mindgate.hc.nl.exemplar.nominate.nominateUserControl.SetDepartment()
```

Also, few users were not able to see few links. Permission were already there but still not able to see it. So I removed the user from Site Collection and added him again and then he was able to see the link.

I did full user profile sync but no luck. Am I missing any post migration changes?

Comment: In 2010, authentication was in classic or claims mode ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. It was Classic authentication

Comment: In SP2013, claims authentication is default authentication so when you migrate content db from 2010 to 2013 you need to convert users from classic to claims as well. Ttry this script in your dev environment first : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sowmyancs/2012/01/06/migrate-users-groups-powershell-script/   and make sure you use farm admin account.

Comment: Hi Vaibhav. Thanks for the Hint.But I cannot use above script as the Domain are same. There is no change. But we can convert the site to Claims based by powershell. There was Session State issue in the code which was created by previous developer. I enable it through powerShell and the code worked. Now I am able to save. Thanks for your heads up on classic to claims.

Comment: Np man.. I am glad your issue has been resolved..